# How do I intercept ember-data response and take alternate action.?

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

I am using latest ember-data library for persistence in my Ember application.

Following is my route definition:

```
export default Ember.Route.extend({

    model: function() {
        return this.store.find('language');
    }
});
```

There are two possible response for this:

- Normal scenario: `{"language":{"id":123,"name": "English"}}`
- Error scenario: `{"error-response":{"status":"398648","message": "internal error."}}` This is a standard error message for all errors.

In both the case, the response is returned with the "http 200 success" status code. So this means that the ember tries to call the resolve callback and generates error for error scenario. I need to handle this for our model definition. Is there any way I can intercept this response and take alternate action?

Comment: I'm having the same issue. I don't have the ability to change the server responses from the setup that was chosen for a different framework ;-/

Answer (score 2):

You could do this in a serializer, check it in there (http://emberjs.com/api/data/classes/DS.RESTSerializer.html#method_normalize) or something along the likes of:

```
export default Ember.Route.extend({

    model: function() {
        return this.store.find('language').then(function(language){
            //perform your check on the response here
            //if language contains error-response this.transitionTo('errorpage')
            //else return language -- that kinda thing.
        });
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

First of all, returning HTTP code 200 while getting an error is more than strange.
Ember expects reasonable response in error situation. It means, if you getting 4xx error, ember will activate Ember.Route.error hook (http://emberjs.com/guides/routing/loading-and-error-substates/#toc_code-error-code-substates); if server responded `validation error` (default code in Ember - 422), than Ember.Adapter will call extractValidationErrors and so on. In short, if you get an error, treat it as an error, and not as a successful response.